# How to check whether a file exists or not and if it exist then i want to close it in finally block in java?

Tags: java

Hi I am beginner in java please explain the things in simple terms.I am making FileHandling.java file in which I try to read from a file and write to other file but after read and write operation I want to close both files but my main problem is how I will get to know whether there was such file or not .On the basis of whether file exists or not I want to close my files.Here is my java code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileHandling {
public static void main(String args[])
{
  FileInputStream in = null;
  FileOutputStream out = null;

  try {
     in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
     out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

     int c;
     while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
     }
  }
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Here some IO problem :"+e);
}
finally {
    System.out.println("Finally Block executed");
                if(in.exists()){in.close();System.out.println("in file closed");}
        else{System.out.println("in file doesn't exist to close operation");}
                if(out.exists()){out.close();System.out.println("out file closed");}
        else{System.out.println("out file doesn't exist to close operation");}
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if they are null

```
finally {
    System.out.println("Finally Block executed");
                if(in != null ){
                     in.close();
                      System.out.println("in file closed");
                 }
        else{
              System.out.println("in file doesn't exist to close operation");
            }
                if(out != null){
              out.close();
               System.out.println("out file closed");}
            else{
               System.out.println("out file doesn't exist to close operation");}
      }

}
```

Alternatively you can use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if using Java 7 or above.

```
try (in = new FileInputStream("input.txt")) {
     try (out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt")) {
}
}
```

This will close the resources automatically once the method completes, without the use of finally block.